# How to find conda python3 environment using cmake in Windows platform?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, windows, cmake, environment

I am currently using cmake to build a project in Windows. The same project had been successfully compiled in MacOS.

compiler: MinGW
platform: Windows11
python3.9: anaconda3 Python3.9 environment
python3.9 environment location: C:\Users\username.conda\envs\sfp
anaconda3 location: D:/ProgramData/anaconda3
anaconda3 python3.11 location: D:/ProgramData/anaconda3/python.exe

The `CMakeLists.txt` file executed the command `find_package(Python 3.7 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter Development NumPy)` in order to find conda python3.9 environment.

I have activated conda environment using `conda activate env` and ran the command `cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"` under the same terminal.

But the cmake procedure kept finding the anaconda python3.11 version. It fails in finding the python3.9 environment.

I tried to add the `PYTHON3_ECECUTABLE` environment variable which points to `C:\Users\username\.conda\envs\sfp\python.exe` but it still failed.

I hoep to find the conda python3.9 environment rather than the python3.11.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the following to your `CMakeLists.txt`

```
set(Python_FIND_VIRTUALENV FIRST)
find_package(Python 3.7 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter Development NumPy)
```

By setting `Python_FIND_VIRTUALENV` to `FIRST` it should look for the venv first. Make sure that the venv is definitely activated before running CMake.

See [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython.html#module:FindPython) for more information on additional options for `FindPython`.

Options for `Python_FIND_VIRTUALENV` are:

- `FIRST`: The virtual environment is used before any other standard paths to look-up for the interpreter. This is the default.
- `ONLY`: Only the virtual environment is used to look-up for the interpreter.
- `STANDARD`: The virtual environment is not used to look-up for the interpreter but environment variable `PATH` is always considered. In this case, variable `Python_FIND_REGISTRY` (Windows) or `CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK` (macOS) can be set with value `LAST` or `NEVER` to select preferably the interpreter from the virtual environment.